# write a PDF file in Arabic using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, character-encoding, arabic, unicode-string

I have added PHP code to generate a PDF file in Arabic and English, but when content is in Arabic it shows like this php arabic output :
[image]

I have checked the font i'm using is compatible with the Arabic language. I am not sure what I am missing. I also have the unicode to be UTF-8 in my configuration file.
here is the code

```
<?php
$paid_amount = $this->invoice_model->calculate_to('paid_amount', $invoice_info->invoices_id);
$client_info = $this->invoice_model->check_by(array('client_id' => $invoice_info->client_id), 'tbl_client');
if (!empty($client_info)) {
    $currency = $this->invoice_model->client_currency_sambol($invoice_info->client_id);
    $client_lang = $client_info->language;
} else {
    $client_lang = 'arabic';
    $currency = $this->invoice_model->check_by(array('code' => config_item('default_currency')), 'tbl_currencies');
}

unset($this->lang->is_loaded[5]);
$language_info = $this->lang->load('sales_lang', $client_lang, TRUE, FALSE, '', TRUE);
$payment_status = $this->invoice_model->get_payment_status($invoice_info->invoices_id);

$uri = $this->uri->segment(3);
if ($uri == 'invoice_email') {
    $img = base_url() . config_item('invoice_logo');
} else {
    $img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . config_item('invoice_logo');
    $a = file_exists($img);
    if (empty($a)) {
        $img = base_url() . config_item('invoice_logo');
    }
}
?>

<table class="clearfix">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="logo" style="margin-top: 8px;">
                <img style=" height: 70px;" src="<?= $img ?>">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="company">
                <h2 class="name"><?= (config_item('company_legal_name_' . $client_lang) ? config_item('company_legal_name_' . $client_lang) : config_item('company_legal_name')) ?></h2>

                <div><?= (config_item('company_address_' . $client_lang) ? config_item('company_address_' . $client_lang) : config_item('company_address')) ?></div>

                <div><?= (config_item('company_city_' . $client_lang) ? config_item('company_city_' . $client_lang) : config_item('company_city')) ?>
                    , <?= config_item('company_zip_code') ?></div>

                <div><?= (config_item('company_country_' . $client_lang) ? config_item('company_country_' . $client_lang) : config_item('company_country')) ?></div>
                <div> <?= config_item('company_phone') ?></div>
                <div><a href="mailto:<?= config_item('company_email') ?>"><?= config_item('company_email') ?></a></div>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="details" class="clearfix">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="client">
                <?php
                if (!empty($client_info)) {
                    $client_name = $client_info->name;
                    $address = $client_info->address;
                    $city = $client_info->city;
                    $zipcode = $client_info->zipcode;
                    $country = $client_info->country;
                    $phone = $client_info->phone;
                    $email = $client_info->email;
                } else {
                    $client_name = '-';
                    $address = '-';
                    $city = '-';
                    $zipcode = '-';
                    $country = '-';
                    $phone = '-';
                    $email = '-';
                }
                ?>
                <h2 class="name"><?= $client_name ?></h2>
                <div class="address"><?= $address ?></div>
                <div class="address"><?= $city ?>, <?= $zipcode ?>
                    ,<?= $country ?></div>
                <div class="address"><?= $phone ?></div>
                <div class="email"><a href="mailto:<?= $email ?>"><?= $email ?></a></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="invoice">
                <h1><?= $invoice_info->reference_no ?></h1>
                <div class="date"><?= $language_info['invoice_date'] ?>
                    :<?= strftime(config_item('date_format'), strtotime($invoice_info->invoice_date)); ?></div>
                <div class="date"><?= $language_info['due_date'] ?>
                    :<?= strftime(config_item('date_format'), strtotime($invoice_info->due_date)); ?></div>
                <?php if (!empty($invoice_info->user_id)) { ?>
                    <div class="date">
                        <?= lang('sales') . ' ' . lang('agent') ?><?php
                        $profile_info = $this->db->where('user_id', $invoice_info->user_id)->get('tbl_account_details')->row();
                        if (!empty($profile_info)) {
                            echo $profile_info->fullname;
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="date"><?= $language_info['payment_status'] ?>: <?= $payment_status ?></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="items" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" page-break-inside: auto;>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="desc"><?= $language_info['items'] ?></th>
        <?php
        $invoice_view = config_item('invoice_view');
        if (!empty($invoice_view) && $invoice_view == '2') {
            ?>
            <th><?= $language_info['hsn_code'] ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
        <th class="unit"><?= $language_info['qty'] ?></th>
        <th class="desc"><?= $language_info['price'] ?></th>
        <th class="unit"><?= $language_info['tax'] ?></th>
        <th class="total"><?= $language_info['total'] ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $invoice_items = $this->invoice_model->ordered_items_by_id($invoice_info->invoices_id);

    if (!empty($invoice_items)) :
        foreach ($invoice_items as $key => $v_item) :
            $item_name = $v_item->item_name ? $v_item->item_name : $v_item->item_desc;
            $item_tax_name = json_decode($v_item->item_tax_name);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="desc"><h3><?= $item_name ?></h3><?= nl2br($v_item->item_desc) ?></td>
                <?php
                $invoice_view = config_item('invoice_view');
                if (!empty($invoice_view) && $invoice_view == '2') {
                    ?>
                    <td><?= $v_item->hsn_code ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                <td class="unit"><?= $v_item->quantity . '   ' . $v_item->unit ?></td>
                <td class="desc"><?= display_money($v_item->unit_cost) ?></td>
                <td class="unit"><?php
                    if (!empty($item_tax_name)) {
                        foreach ($item_tax_name as $v_tax_name) {
                            $i_tax_name = explode('|', $v_tax_name);
                            echo '<small class="pr-sm">' . $i_tax_name[0] . ' (' . $i_tax_name[1] . ' %)' . '</small>' . display_money($v_item->total_cost / 100 * $i_tax_name[1]) . ' <br>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?></td>
                <td class="total"><?= display_money($v_item->total_cost) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr class="total">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="1"><?= $language_info['sub_total'] ?></td>
        <td><?= display_money($this->invoice_model->calculate_to('invoice_cost', $invoice_info->invoices_id)) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($invoice_info->discount_total > 0): ?>
        <tr class="total">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="1"><?= $language_info['discount'] ?>(<?php echo $invoice_info->discount_percent; ?>%)</td>
            <td> <?= display_money($this->invoice_model->calculate_to('discount', $invoice_info->invoices_id)) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif;
    $tax_info = json_decode($invoice_info->total_tax);
    $tax_total = 0;
    if (!empty($tax_info)) {
        $tax_name = $tax_info->tax_name;
        $total_tax = $tax_info->total_tax;
        if (!empty($tax_name)) {
            foreach ($tax_name as $t_key => $v_tax_info) {
                $tax = explode('|', $v_tax_info);
                $tax_total += $total_tax[$t_key];
                ?>
                <tr class="total">
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td colspan="1"><?= $tax[0] . ' (' . $tax[1] . ' %)' ?></td>
                    <td> <?= display_money($total_tax[$t_key]); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
        }
    } ?>
    <?php if ($tax_total > 0): ?>
        <tr class="total">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="1"><?= $language_info['total'] . ' ' . $language_info['tax'] ?></td>
            <td><?= display_money($tax_total); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif;
    if ($invoice_info->adjustment > 0): ?>
        <tr class="total">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="1"><?= $language_info['adjustment'] ?></td>
            <td><?= display_money($invoice_info->adjustment); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
    <tr class="total">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="1"><?= $language_info['total'] ?></td>
        <td><?= display_money($this->invoice_model->calculate_to('total', $invoice_info->invoices_id), $currency->symbol); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $paid_amount = $this->invoice_model->calculate_to('paid_amount', $invoice_info->invoices_id);
    if ($paid_amount > 0) {
        $total = $language_info['total_due'];
        if ($paid_amount > 0) {
            $text = 'style="color:red"';
            ?>
            <tr class="total">
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td colspan="1"><?= $language_info['paid_amount'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $paid_amount ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } else {
            $text = '';
        } ?>
        <tr class="total">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="1"><span <?= $text ?>><?= $total ?></span></td>
            <td><?= display_money($this->invoice_model->calculate_to('invoice_due', $invoice_info->invoices_id), $currency->symbol); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<div id="thanks"><?= lang('thanks') ?>!</div>
<div id="notices">
    <div class="notice"><?= $invoice_info->notes ?></div>
</div>
<?php
$invoice_view = config_item('invoice_view');
if (!empty($invoice_view) && $invoice_view > 0) {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .panel {
            margin-bottom: 21px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        }

        .panel-custom .panel-heading {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #2b957a;
        }

        .panel .panel-heading {
            border-bottom: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .panel-heading {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
            border-top-right-radius: 3px;
            border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        }

        .panel-title {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="panel panel-custom" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="border:1px solid #dde6e9;border-bottom: 2px solid #57B223;">
            <div class="panel-title"><?= lang('tax_summary') ?></div>
        </div>
        <table class="items" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" page-break-inside: auto;>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="desc"><?= $language_info['items'] ?></th>
                <?php
                $invoice_view = config_item('invoice_view');
                if (!empty($invoice_view) && $invoice_view == '2') {
                    ?>
                    <th><?= lang('hsn_code') ?></th>
                <?php } ?>
                <th class="unit"><?= $language_info['qty'] ?></th>
                <th class="desc"><?= $language_info['tax'] ?></th>
                <th class="unit" style="text-align: right"><?= $language_info['total_tax'] ?></th>
                <th class="total" style="text-align: right"><?= $language_info['tax_excl_amt'] ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $total_tax = 0;
            $total_cost = 0;
            if (!empty($invoice_items)) :
                foreach ($invoice_items as $key => $v_item) :
                    $item_tax_name = json_decode($v_item->item_tax_name);
                    $tax_amount = 0;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desc"><?= $v_item->item_name ?></td>
                        <?php
                        $invoice_view = config_item('invoice_view');
                        if (!empty($invoice_view) && $invoice_view == '2') {
                            ?>
                            <td><?= $v_item->hsn_code ?></td>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <td class="unit"><?= $v_item->quantity . '   ' . $v_item->unit ?></td>
                        <td class="desc"><?php
                            if (!empty($item_tax_name)) {
                                foreach ($item_tax_name as $v_tax_name) {
                                    $i_tax_name = explode('|', $v_tax_name);
                                    $tax_amount += $v_item->total_cost / 100 * $i_tax_name[1];
                                    echo '<small class="pr-sm">' . $i_tax_name[0] . ' (' . $i_tax_name[1] . ' %)' . '</small>' . display_money($v_item->total_cost / 100 * $i_tax_name[1]) . ' <br>';
                                }
                            }
                            $total_cost += $v_item->total_cost;
                            $total_tax += $tax_amount;
                            ?></td>
                        <td class="unit" style="text-align: right"><?= display_money($tax_amount) ?></td>
                        <td class="total" style="text-align: right"><?= display_money($v_item->total_cost) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr class="total">
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td><?= $language_info['total'] ?></td>
                <td><?= display_money($total_tax) ?></td>
                <td><?= display_money($total_cost) ?></td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<footer>
    <?= config_item('invoice_footer') ?>
</footer>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: (I seem to be missing `PDF` in the code.)

Comment: What is the library you are using? TCPDF?